# My Java app running out of memory

Tags: java, performance, memory-management

My application is running out of memory while performing an operation with a large data. The data is a Java List and is around 100K elements in size.
`PersistData` is the class which implements the operation and `PersistDataIntoDB` is the class which does the actual operation. Because the operation time consuming, the caller to `PersistData` gets a response saying the operation is started and there are additional APIs to get the status of the operation.

Also, the entire operation in concurrent and there are multiple callers to the operation.

Here is what the code looks like (I hope its readable).

```
public class PersistData {
    public Boolean persistData(List<ClassA> dataRecs) {
        //some checks (smaller operation)
        persistDataInDifferentThread(dataRecs);
        //if no errors in checks return true
        return true;
    }

    private void persistDataInDifferentThread(List<ClassA> dataRecs) {
        Thread runnerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List convertedList = constructClassBUsingClassA(dataRecs);
                    PersistDataIntoDB dbPersist = new PersistDataIntoDB();
                    dbPersist.persistDataInDB(convertedList);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

     private List<ClassB> constructClassBUsingClassA(List<ClassA> dataRecs) {
    List<ClassB> tempList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataRecs.size(); i++) {
        ClassA tempRec = dataRecs.get(i);
        ClassB tempRecB = new ClassB();
        //put stuff from tempRec to tempRecB
        tempList.add(tempRecB);
    }
    return tempList;
}

}
```

Class which does the persistance.

```
public class PersistDataIntoDB {
     public Boolean persistDataInDB(List<ClassB> dataRecs){
        //if all goes well return true
        return true;
    }
}
```

My question is if my method `persistDataInDifferentThread` can be refactored ?because while it is running, there are two large Lists in memory and the call to `persistDataInDB` take long time to finish and the garbage collector may not be unloading the `List<ClassA>` even though I don’t need it after calling `persistDataInDB`.

Is my above analysis wrong? I just have to increase the max heap because I am dealing with large data?

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've provided, one obvious problem with your current implementation is that there is no limit to the number of threads repeated calls to persistData will launch. Call it frequently enough and you can easily run out of resources. You probably want to consider a queue and consumer or threadpool approach.

Comment: can you show how you setup the lists / what's in the lists.

Comment: Are you sure you need to create PersistDataIntoDB dbPersist for every list? It seems like this is class with method that could be static.

Comment: @Jan the list contains elements of one of my data-structure. The data-stucture ClassA is slightly different than ClassB, so, I construct objects of ClassB for each object of ClassA which is there is the list supplied by the caller.

Comment: And could you show full code of constructClassBUsingClassA? It is unclear how you convert one class to another?

Comment: @sphinks updated my question with with I am doing in constructClassBUsingClassA

Comment: @pvg, I do maintain a counter for the max calls which can be configured. Implementing a threadpool would be ideal but thats more for me right now.

Comment: @dRv what happens when you set the # of threads to 1? Do you ever OOM? As to pool, it's a fairly trivial thing to implement with the available classes in the concurrent package. Probably a dozen lines of code.

Comment: @drv another easily fixed thing is - you mentioned your list is large. Converting it wholesale into another large list seems unnecessary, given you can convert element by element as you are persisting.

Comment: @pvg with max thread to 1 it never hits OOM. With maxheap as 128m I am able to increase the counter to 12

Comment: @dRv hang on, your maxheap is regularly 128m or less?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97702/discussion-between-drv-and-pvg).

Answer (score 2):

> Is my above analysis wrong? I just have to increase the max heap because I am dealing with large data?

Yes, and yes.

1)  Using multiple threads does not increase or reduce the amount of heap space used.

2)  If the heap fills up, then the JVM will make every effort to reclaim space before throwing an OOME.

The only thing that might make a difference is if one thread creates the list and passes it to the second instance to be persisted ... and also hangs onto a reference to the list.  That might cause the list to remain reachable longer than it needs to be.

I guess you could also get into trouble if you have multiple runner threads persisting multiple lists, and the work is arriving faster than you can process it.  If that is the problem, then you need to do something to control the rate at which you *accept* the requests.

Comment: Thanks. I have yet to confirm "hangs onto a reference to the list" part

Comment: My understanding is that @ `dbPersist.persistDataInDB(convertedList);` , the two lists (lists of ClassA and ClassB) are in memory. But I don't need the list of ClassB because I have already processed it. Right?

Comment: @dRV persisted list will be delete from memory once persistDataInDifferentThread finished, because application lost link to this list.

Comment: Once the list of ClassB has been created, there is no *need* for anything to keep a reference to the list of ClassA.  (If you have done that, then you *will* increase the heap usage ... but the solution is "don't".)